# Testing Angular 2 components with @Input

Tags: angular

I'm trying to test my Angular 2 components, instantiating with `new MyComponent()`. However, for components that take `@Input`s, how might I pass those in? Then, if instantiated, say I'd like to change an input. Is that just a matter of reassigning to the variable I'd passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an instance with `new` there is nothing else you can do to assigning to the field. You can use the `TestComponentBuilder` to get change detection and binding.

Below a Dart code example which tests a `BwuArraySelector` component. 
I assume you can figure out how to do it in TS.

```dart
/// Component only for testing BwuArraySelector
@Component(
    selector: 'test-cmp-singleconfigured',
    directives: const [BwuArraySelector],
    template: '''
<bwu-array-selector #singleConfigured
  [items]='[{"name": "one"},{"name": "two"},{"name": "three"}]'>
</bwu-array-selector>
''')
class SingleConfigured {
  @ViewChild('singleConfigured') BwuArraySelector arraySelector;
}
```

...

```dart
// inject the TextComponentBuilder and create a component instance
ngTest('single selection', (TestComponentBuilder tcb) async {
  ComponentFixture tc = await tcb.createAsync(SingleConfigured);
  tc..detectChanges();
  BwuArraySelector el =
      (tc.componentInstance as SingleConfigured).arraySelector;
```

The call to `detectChanges()` initializes the inputs of `BwuArraySelector` with the values from the `SingleConfigured` test components template bindings.

Comment: Yeah, I'd been under this impression as well, since obviously the constructor parameters are already reserved for whatever you put in there yourself... But if my component has calculated fields based on those inputs, how can I tests those properly if I can't use inputs in testing?

Comment: Sorry, seems I'd only written half my comment by the time you'd seen it already. In any case, still not sure how to proceed. :(

Comment: Seems you're right. I added an example. Sorry for the Dart code, I don't know TS.

Comment: Hah. And here I was expecting one would use a different approach during testing. I guess you have a point though -- if you can just do it the same way, why not I guess. :)
P.S. For the component I'd barely even notice that's Dart rather than TS/JS, the differences seem kinda subtle.

Comment: Yup, syntax difference is subtle.